# Autocomplete in Angular 2 is displaying id instead of name in input box after selecting

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am implementing an auto complete in Angular 2. I can Filter the result when I type letters in the input box. But when I choose an item, instead of getting the name, it changes to the id instead. Please see image below:

[image]

But when I click or choose an item, this what goes to the input box:

[image]

The name is gone and is substituted with an id which will be confusing to the enduser. Below is how I implemented it.

**.ts**

```
glMasterList: ParamGLMaster[] = [];
filteredGlMasterList: Observable<any[]>;
getGlMaster() {
    this.as.getGlMaster().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.glMasterList = data;
      this.filteredGlMasterList = this.GLCode.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(""),
        map(gl => (gl ? this.filterGlMasterList(gl) : this.glMasterList.slice()))
      )
    });
  }
  filterGlMasterList(name: string) {
    return this.glMasterList.filter(
      ml => ml.GLDesc.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0
    );
  }
```

**.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input
      type="text"
      matInput
      [matAutocomplete]="auto1"
      formControlName="GLCode"
      placeholder="GL Code"
    />
    <!-- <mat-select placeholder="GL Code" formControlName="GLCode">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of glMasterList" [value]="item.GLCode" (onSelectionChange)="onChange($event, item.GLDesc)">{{item.GLDesc}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select> -->
    <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let gl of (filteredGlMasterList | async)"
        [value]="gl.GLCode"
      >
        <span>{{ gl.GLDesc }}</span> |
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-error *ngIf="GLCode.invalid" style="color: red;">{{
      GlCodeError()
    }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

'GLCode' is the Id and 'GLDesc' is the name. Can you please how to correct this? Thank you.

Comment: replace [value]="gl.GLCode" with [value]="gl.GLDesc".

Comment: That's the first thing that I thought was the solution. The problem with that is, I need the GLCode in the database since that serves as the Id

Comment: If I replace the GLCode with GLDesc as the value, as soon as I submit the form, the GLDesc is passed since that is what the [value] was

Comment: Then you have to listen for onchange event.

Comment: Yes. I was helped by @Sneha Pawar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with following

```
<mat-option
    *ngFor="let gl of (filteredGlMasterList | async)"
    [value]="gl.GLDesc"
  >
   {{ gl.GLDesc }}
  </mat-option>
```

See this - https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

Comment: Sorry. I don't get what you mean.. Your code example is my code exactly..

Comment: yeah, remove it and check once

Comment: I don't see how removing the span tag will help but I did that and I still get the same issue...

Comment: have you checked the link that I sent?

Comment: Yes I did and thank you. I can see that they don't have the span tag. But I don't think that is the solution. The span tag just servers as a container.

Comment: replace [value]="gl.GLCode" with [value]="gl.GLDesc" same as they did

Comment: Oh. That's the first thing that I thought was the solution. The problem with that is, I need the GLCode in the database since that serves as the Id. If I replace the GLCode with GLDesc as the [value], as soon as I submit the form, the GLDesc is passed since that is what the [value] was

Comment: what is the functionality on this (onSelectionChange)="onChange($event, item.GLDesc)?

Comment: You have a point there. I was hoping I can get away with it without creating another method. But I guess there is no other way.. Thank you.

Comment: No, but you can use blur event for the input box Or if  you just want to get the GLcode of the selected item you can get in the onSelectionChange event just add GLcode to method ex.(onSelectionChange)="onChange($event, item.GLCode, item.GLDesc)